# How do I get this div to float further to the left than this other div?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Really simple question time:

I have two divs.

```
<div id="1">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <p>goodbye</p>
</div>
```

#1 is floated to the left. #2 is floated to the left. what can I do, short of changing the HTML to push #2 to the left of #1? I am aware of a solve using absolute and relative positioning but it would be super if there were a way to do it a more 'dynamic' way (like float)

[image: This be wat i want]

Comment: I assume float:right is also out of the question?

Comment: So you want to do it **without changing the HTML**?

Comment: The reason I am asking this is because #2 is my left sidebar and #1 is my content column. I want it to be floated because ideally when you resize the browser to really skinny, the sidebar will pop down to underneath my content column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **float:right** and an outside container

**CSS**

```
 #outside { float: left }
 #a { float:right }
 #b { float:right }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="outside">
   <div id="a">
     <p>hello</p>
   </div>
   <div id="b">
     <p>goodbye</p>
   </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: ha! That's much more elegant than I was expecting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simple float right the first div?

http://jsfiddle.net/notme/2w4Ch/

Answer (score 0):

Note: ID's cant begin with numbers.
Just remove the float left for id 'one'

```
#one{}
#two{float: left}
```